# If I install a package in only one virtual environment, do I need to reinstall it in other virtual environments?

Tags: python, tensorflow, virtualenv

For example, if I install TensorFlow in one virtual environment, do I need to reinstall it again when I make a new project in a different virtual environment? This seems very bothersome, and I usually only need one version of a package.

Also, I want to install TensorFlow using Anaconda but the only way is using a virtual environment: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/tensorflow/ Any ideas on how I can install it system wide?

Comment: That's the entire point of a virtual environment

Comment: @Sayse That seems like it'll take a long time if each project has a dozen package dependencies. For best practice, are there specific packages that should be installed system wide to save time or should they all be env specific?

Comment: @Goldname Always env specific. System wide packages have a certain version. If you project needs a newer version, good luck with configuration management. Packages which you should use system wide: pip, pipenv

Comment: It'll take an even longer time when your legacy projects need updating to support newer versions of packages because your newer projects require them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For example, if I install TensorFlow in one virtual environment, do I need to reinstall it again when I make a new project in a different virtual environment? This seems very bothersome, and I usually only need one version of a package.

Yes

> Also, I want to install TensorFlow using Anaconda but the only way is using a virtual environment: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/tensorflow/ Any ideas on how I can install it system wide?

Try to use venv for every project.

Based on your comments and your question you can prepare a pip command to install everything in a place. Its space-delimited list.

```
pip install package1 package2 package3 package4
```

Comment: What about for the base environment? Do all environments inherit packages from it?

Comment: If you want to use base environment still you can use `--system-site-packages` while creating your venv

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you want packages per virtual environment. It's fairly easy to use with tools like [pipenv](https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/en/latest/).

The reason you want packages per virtual environment is version management per project. If you have 10 projects locally and only use system wide packages. They all need to use the same version. You can get away with it, but it's is something you want to avoid.

Comment: Do you know if for Anaconda environments that I make inherit all the packages from base environment ?

Answer (score 2):

If you use conda environments you can clone and share them.

`conda create --name mynewcloneenv --clone myoldoriginalenv`